# Linq Insert: The column name ' ' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF, I am not able to insert a data into table.

Question class look like this

```
[Table("QUESTION")]    
public class QUESTION
{      
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int q_id { get; set; }

    public string questname { get; set; }

    public string optionname { get; set; }
}
```

Insert method

```
public string Save(QUESTION newquestion)
{
    try
    {
        using (dbcontextdata Context = new dbcontextdata())
        {
            QUESTION dbquest = new QUESTION();
            dbquest.id = newquestion.id;
            dbquest.q_id  = newquestion.q_id;
            dbquest.questname  = newquestion.questname;
            dbquest.optionname  = newquestion.optionname;
            Context.QUESTIONs.Add(dbquest);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

when I post the data, it shows error in `SaveChanges`()

> The column name 'q_id' is specified more than once in the SET clause
>   or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one
>   value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column
>   is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns
>   into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.

Here `q_id` is FK, help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly define `q_id`as a foreign key like the following.

```
 [ForeignKey("MyForeignTable")]
 public int q_id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Index(IsUnique=true)]
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int q_id { get; set; }
```